# No route matches {:action=>"completed", :controller=>"lifetimes", :lifetime_id=>14} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

When a user clicks the checkmark he should be prompted to input the date when he completed his challenge.

```
<%= link_to completed_path({ lifetime_id: lifetime.id }), data: { modal: true }, class: "btn" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> #Checkmark
<% end %>
```

Now that the user completed his challenge he should update the `:deadline` via **_completed.html.erb** to whatever date he completed his `lifetime` challenge.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@lifetime, url: lifetime_path({ lifetime_id: @lifetime }), remote: request.xhr?, html: { data: { modal: true } }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :deadline %>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
        Save
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
get '/completed/:id', to: 'lifetimes#completed', as: 'completed'
```

**lifetimes_controller**

```
def completed
  @lifetime = current_user.lifetimes.find(params[:lifetime_id])
  respond_modal_with @lifetime
end
```

What do I need to fix to get rid of this error. I'm taking code I found elsewhere and trying to adjust for my purposes so I'm not fully understanding how it all applies.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completed route is expecting the `:id` parameter and you are passing the `:lifetime_id`.

To get rid of the error that you are getting use `:lifetime_id` instead of `:id` in 'completed' route like following:

```
get '/completed/:lifetime_id', to: 'lifetimes#completed', as: 'completed'
```

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted `@Veets` answer, and wanted to add something extra.

In your routes, you're calling `completed/:lifetime_id` & sending to the `lifetimes` controller; surely you'd be better using the following:

```
#config/routes
resources :lifetimes, only: [--put-whatever-you-need-here] do
   get :completed, as: :completed #-> url.com/lifetimes/:lifetime_id/completed
end
```

If you wanted to use `:id`, you'd be able to set `on: :member`, as according to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes):

> You can leave out the `:on` option, this will create the same member
>   route except that the resource id value will be available in
>   `params[:photo_id]` instead of `params[:id]`.

--

Also, when you use a `<%=form_for` method, or similar, you should really make it so that your `object` contains all the data required for the form to determine the path:

```
<%= simple_form_for @lifetime, data: { modal: true }, class: "btn" do %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this well thought our answer. You successfully stole the green arrow :)

Comment: lol thanks, but it wasn't my intention at all. `Veets` needs the rep more than me, you should really give him the green :)